# session values are not retained in IE7

Tags: session-variables

In a application which is developed with the combination of both asp and asp.net.The application gets  Inactivity logout error only with IE7 browser. But it works fine with the other version of the browsers(IE8 & IE9). We Found that this incaticity logout error occurs since the session values are lost or gets reset only in IE7 browser and the session values are retained in the other version of the browsers.I need to retain the session values with IE7 browser also any help would be appreciated.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems unlikely, here is my first attempt at a solution:

Confirm that the "accept cookies" setting is turned on in the IE7 browsers with which you are testing.

Comment: Hi I tried this option and it is already enabled.It didnot work.